# How to convert a context free grammar (could generate regular language) to a right-linear grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, nfa

The context free grammar: (e represents epsilon)

```
  S --> aSb|aSa|bSa|bSb|e
```

It could generate regular language which means it can be converted to a right linear grammar. Is there a general rule to convert CFG into a RLG?

Comment: So in this case, your desired output would be `S --> aaS|abS|baS|bbS|e`?

Comment: This question might be better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com or http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

There is no general algorithm for converting a CFG to a right-linear grammar because right-linear grammars generate precisely the regular languages, which are a strict subset of the context-free languages.  Accordingly, if a general algorithm existed that performed this transformation, it would prove all context-free languages are regular, which is known to be false.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If there is no general rule to do that, could you show me how to convert the CFG above into a RLG?

Comment: @henry- If you look at the above grammar, you'll note that it generates all even-length strings made from a's and b's.  Given that insight, you can try creating, from scratch, a right linear grammar that generates the same language.